# AngularJS resets value of input when using different ways to enter data

Tags: angularjs

I need to be able to enter data using keyboard and buttons. In this example the input is bound to model attribute. When using both keyboard and button to enter value at some point input is being reset. How to fix it?

http://embed.plnkr.co/XSjC6OHvlnySie9b5h8K/

**UPDATE**

Solution by *MarcoS* is not fully functional since when:

value in input field does not match `ng-pattern` then pressing button 1 resets value.

Comment: you resetting it here: $scope.reservation.number = num;, did you wanted to do '+=' ?

Comment: At start if it is equals to `null` or `undefined` I just assign the value. Else I need to append it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose it depends on `ng-pattern` you set (exactly 8 digits): only when you input the eight digit your model is updated...

See my fork'd [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/IBwxvWUxDGSgPaokTDIJ?p=preview) (I only added scope variable in view to make it clearer...)

Comment: Button must append to string not add (pressing 2 times button `1` must return `11` not `2`)

Comment: Yes, sorry, corrected my plnkr. Reverted to `num.toString()`, after changing to `num` while testing... Does it work as you expect, now?

Comment: No, try to type `123` using your keyboard then press button `1`. See what happens

Comment: That behaivour is explained by my answer (ng-pattern). Try typing `12345678` and then button `1`... :-)